# java programming get the date from a calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar

i am new to java programming .i do not whether it is possible to connect the external calendar to a java program.i have no previous experience on this.So please help me.

Comment: Yes and no, it would depend on the calendar system you're trying to work with

Comment: Need much more detail friend. What library you had a look at for instance, this kind of thing. You can help you not do the research for you.

Comment: please put up more information on what kind of calendar, what have you tried as of now etc

Comment: what do you mean by the calendar system?

Comment: @UNR Please edit your Question to be more clear. What do you mean by "external" calendar? Also, I'm glad to see you want to participate on StackOverflow. But please **search before posting**. [Hundreds of basic date-time in Java questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+date) have already been posted and answered.

Comment: thank you i will find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Schuss ins Blaue*

```
long currentTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(currentTimeInMillis);
```